# Difference in the meaning between "of + ~ing" and "to infinitive"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

What is the exact difference in the meaning and the grammar between

> "The quickest way of contacting the police station is to use your
>   cellphone"

and

> "The quickest way to contact the police station is to use your
>   cellphone"

I got the following answer (by A. Galloway ) in response to a specific question.

> =====================================================================
>
> the following answer (by A. Galloway )

English is notorious for using the -ing ending (which normally denotes something being done in the present progressive tense) in place if the verb's infinitive form. The sentence would most accurately be read as:

> The quickest way of contacting the police station is to use your
>   cellphone."
>
> =
>
> "The quickest way to contact the police station is to use your
>   cellphone."
>
> ===================================================================

I have not yet been able to distinguish between "of ~ ing" and "to infinitive" at all.
If these sentences have the exact same meaning,
I would appreciate it if you could give me a lot of examples.

Comment: Why must there be a difference?  *I like to answer ELL questions* = *I like answering ELL questions.*  :)

Comment: There may be some differences in where each form can be used (if I could come up with a list of them I would write a proper answer), but there is no difference in meaning at all between the two sentences in your question.

Comment: The sentence could as easily be _"The quickest way to contact the police station is **using** your cellphone"._ There is more often a difference in _usage_ than in _meaning_. Have you tried searching this very site for the phrase "gerund or infinitive"? Type _gerund or infinitive_ in the "Search Q&A" field and press "enter". There are scores of questions. Have you studied the _gerund_ in English?

Comment: I learned about gerund and infinitive. I learned about the difference between gerund and infinitive. However, in gerund and infinitive used in many English sentences, there seems to be something I can not understand the difference. I know very simple Korean sentences that foreigners never understand. Even though there are obvious differences, Koreans explain that there is no difference for foreigners. If the words are different, I think it will be different also in English

Comment: Why do you think English is any different than Korean? The difference is that now you are the "foreigner"! There is no "exact" difference in meaning, but there are many differences in usage. Sometimes the meanings are quite different: consider _"He'll never forget **spending** that much"_ and _"He'll never forget **to spend** that much"_. There is no rule to follow. You have to learn the differences one by one, usage by usage, verb by verb.

Comment: As you pointed out, I am learning one by one. The way I do now is to get rid of the curiosity one by one. I do not know English well, but in this way I seem to know a little bit about my questions. I have seen English for 35 years. For 35 years I have seen English, but I have hardly been able to read it. Now I am making great improvements in reading the most English. Of course, I'm just using the translator to ask questions. I can not use this level of English. If you improve your English, I will be able to communicate more accurately.

Comment: I try to improve my English every day! Your comment here is a good example of why you should **NEVER RELY ON GOOGLE** "translate" or similar utilities. Your previous comment, undoubtedly written by the google "translator", is not what you intended to say. Google "translate" is just plain wrong much of the time, and often hilariously funny. You seem to have good comprehension of English. Forget about google "translate", keep working and studying, and one day, as we say in English, the "light bulb will go on."

Comment: Knowing a small difference may be knowing a huge difference to someone. I think that this is really important in my position to learn a foreign language. I can see that my reading ability is improving whenever I find out these small differences. The same process occurs when foreigners who come to Korea learn Hangul. Koreans think it is natural, but there are many things Koreans rarely explain, even though foreigners are very curious about very very small difference. There is really a difference, and foreigners need to know the difference so they can use Hangul for granted.

Comment: Andrew// do you think that  " I like to answer ELL questions = I like answering ELL questions. = I like of answering ELL questions " ?

Answer (score 1):

1. "The quickest way of contacting the police station is to use your cellphone"
2. "The quickest way to contact the police station is to use your cellphone"

There is no difference in meaning between 1 and 2 but 2 is preferred and less awkward.

As far as differences:

3. He stopped smoking.
4. He stopped to smoke.

4 means: 'He stopped walking, then started smoking'.  3 means he stopped smoking for the rest of his life.

Comment: How do we know he stopped smoking for the rest of his life? I believe he stopped smoking only until leaving the restaurant, after being told by a waiter to extinguish his cigarette. How do we know he was walking? I'm sure he was swimming.

Comment: Can we descirbe "He stopped smoking" as "He stopped of smoking" ? Can we describe "He stopped to smoke" as "He stopped for smoking" ? IF so, does "He stopped of smoking" and "He stopped to smoke" have a different meaning? IF so, does "of + ~ing" and " to infinitive" have a different meaning in some cases ? In some cases, "of + ing" and "to infinitive" have the same meaning, and in some cases "of + ing" and "to infinitive" mean different?